# c++ release memory of vector containing custom class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to release the memory of vector manually. The element of vector is custom class.

I googled that clear and shrink_to_fit will do the job. But It do not work with vector of custom class and work with vector of int.

Below is the test code and definition of the custom class.

```
using namespace std;
class HandsDisQuality{
public:
    unordered_map<Hands,float,HandsHash> handsdis;
    // handslist is the keys of handsdis
    std::vector<Hands> handslist;

    HandsDisQuality();
    HandsDisQuality(std::vector<Hands>& v);
    HandsDisQuality(unordered_map<Hands,float,HandsHash>& inputhandsdis);
    HandsDisQuality(float range);
    void init(unordered_map<Hands,float,HandsHash>& inputhandsdis);
    float operator[](Hands& key);
    float get(Hands& key, float defaultvalue);
    float sum();
    int size();
    void removecard(Card& card);
    void removecard(Hands & hand, vector<Card> & board);

    bool normalize();
    void printdata(char sep = '\t');
    std::vector<Hands> * gethands();
    Json::Value tojson();
    void loadfromjson(Json::Value & jsonvalue);
    void test();
    static vector<HandsDisQuality> Generateophands(vector<float> oprange);
    static vector<HandsDisQuality> Generateophands(float oprange);
};

int main() {
vector<HandsDisQuality> v(500000,HandsDisQuality(0.3));
// 14GB
    cout << "init over"<<endl;
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    v.clear();
// 14GB
    cout << "after clear"<<endl;
    cin >> a;
    v.shrink_to_fit();
// 14GB
    cout << "release memory"<<endl;
    cin >> a;
}

int main() {
vector<int> v(500000000,0);
// 2.34GB
    cout << "init over"<<endl;
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    v.clear();
// 2.34GB
    cout << "after clear"<<endl;
    cin >> a;
    v.shrink_to_fit();
// 400MB
    cout << "release memory"<<endl;
    cin >> a;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what you measure with `// 14GB` ? As released memory may still be assigned to application for later use.

Comment: @Jarod42 I measure 14GB with htop. And the memory is not assigned for later use, since the program use more and more memory and then run out of memory even if I've released those vector that is not used anymore.

Comment: I meant do `while (true) {/*main content*/}` and unless fragmentation of memory, your memory should stay stable.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are right. The memory usage goes up is because I allocate many other memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to swap it if you really want to clear the memory:

```
v.swap(vector<HandsDisQuality>());
```

`shrink_to_fit` doesn't have to shrink, it's non-binding:

> It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.

Comment: I tried "vector<HandsDisQuality>().swap(v);" and the memory is still not released.

Comment: And `v` has now a capacity of `0` after the call? Are you sure you don't have another memory leak somewhere? As @Jarod42` said, your application may not give back the memory to the OS, depends on the configuration.